# How does std::map operator[] cause memory leak with fundamental data types?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stdmap, memory-leak-detector

I'm using [Visual Leak Detector](http://sites.google.com/site/dmoulding/vld) to detect memory leaks, and have encountered many instances of memory leaks in lines such as:

```
class SomeClass
{
    // ...
    std::map<long,long> some_map;

    void func(long a_long, long b_long)
    {
        some_map[a_long] = b_long;  // here be a memory leak
    }
}
```

How is this even possible? there are no pointers here, no object instantiation.

Could it be a memory leak that is a side-effect of having the program crash due to something else? Would a program crash or exit(1) cause the map to not be destructed cleanly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you've posted here is perfectly fine and shouldn't cause any leaks, so there are a few possible culprits:

1. Some STL implementations use custom allocators that retain dynamically-allocated memory without freeing it in order to make future allocations faster.  It's possible that you have such an implementation and that it's using this optimization, which would look like a leak from the perspective of a memory-checker.
2. If the program terminates abnormally, then the `map` destructor (or any object destructor, for that matter) won't be invoked, which would definitely cause the memory leak.

Comment: You and Peter's answer should be combined.

Comment: @Jonathan- According to section 18.3.8 of the spec, "Automatic objects are not destroyed as a result of calling `exit()`."  So yes, calling `exit` will prevent the destructor from running.

Answer (score 5):

There's no memory leak there, but there are instantiations.

When you insert into a map, it needs to create a new node in its tree (a map is usually a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree)). Typically, the map will allocate dynamic memory for every insertion, and this is no different for primitive types, user-defined types or pointers.